# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: when creating file from URL(works in debug mode)

Tags: java, image, url, io

I'm trying to convert URL to file and save it to the folder.

```
public void saveFileToStorage(String url, Long timestamp, Integer deviceId) {
    String folder = "D:\\Work\\S3\\" + deviceId;
    File directory = new File(folder);
    File file = new File(folder, timestamp + ".jpg");
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
    }
    try {
        URL link = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But this code works fine only in debug mode, when I start a program, most of the time it will throw - "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException" I tried to read image from URL only by using ImageIO.read and without HttpURLConnection, but it will always throw - "Can't get input stream from URL!"(in debug mode still works). Is there a way to fix this? Thank you

**UPD: Solved!**
The problems was in url from which file uploads with delay, and because program works fast, it didn't have time to download file and threw FileNotFoundException. For now I added `Thread.slepp(1000)` and it works.

Comment: What happens if you do `file = new File()` after the `mkdir()`? How about if you assign `boolean foo = directory.mkdir()` and print out `foo`, does it say "true"?

Comment: @MikeKim I did `file = new File()` after the `mkdir()`, but it didn't help, still same error and works only half of the time... Regarding `boolean foo = directory.mkdir()` - it prints true if the folder doesn't exist and it creates one, if the folder is already created, its skips that if statement

Comment: *"I'm trying to convert URL to file and save it to the folder."* - For this task, you should probably just download the URL to file using an HTTP library. Unless you also need to convert the image to JPEG, you can leave `ImageIO` out of it, and save time. `ImageIO.read(URL)`, I believe, is intended mostly for local resources (ie. `ClassLoader.getResource(..)` URLs).  If you need the conversion, I suggest using 2 steps, first download, then convert. Very odd if your code works only in debug mode though...